# Why AWS CDK Typescript makes extra Subnets in VPC

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I used the below code few months ago with old versions of CDK and Typescript. Today I updated to latest CDK version 1.85.0 and Typescript 4.1.3.

In Old version, I got 3 Subnets in VPC (my expected behaviour). Today with new versions, I got 6 Subnets namely public1Subnet1, public1Subnet2, public1Subnet3, public2Subnet1, etc...

So can anyone explain this behaviour?

```
const publicSubnets = [
  {
    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
    name: 'public1',
    cidrMask: 24
  },
  {
    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
    name: 'public2',
    cidrMask: 24
  },
  {
    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
    name: 'public3',
    cidrMask: 24
  }
]

const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'vpc', {
  
  cidr: "10.0.0.0/16",
  maxAzs: 3,
  natGateways: 0,
  subnetConfiguration: [...publicSubnets]

});
```

Comment: can you do a `cdk synth` and post the result?

Comment: The subnets are created per availability zone, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.Vpc.html

Be aware that environment-agnostic stacks will be created with access to only 2 AZs, so to use more than 2 AZs, be sure to specify the account and region on your stack.

So 6 subnets (3 public for 2 AZs) seems like a correct count.